# Compactness of the set of $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, compactness, orthogonal-matrices

Show that the set of all orthogonal matrices in the set of all $n \times n$ matrices  endowed with any norm topology is compact.

Comment: The column vectors of an orthogonal matrix are unit vectors. And there are $n$ column vectors.

Comment: It would also be expeditious to use the operator norm.  What is the operator norm of an orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 15):

Recall a compact subset of $R^{n \times n}$ is a set that is closed and bounded. One way to show closedness is to observe that the orthogonal matrices are the inverse image of the element $I$ under the continuous map $M \rightarrow MM^T$. Boundedness follows for example from the fact that each column or row is a vector of magnitude $1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this implies boundedness?

Comment: Each entry must be of absolute value at most 1, since the column it is in has magnitude 1, for example.

Comment: Yes but what is the norm?

Comment: "Magnitude 1" means Euclidean norm here.

Comment: Why is the map continuous? Can you explain it a little bit more? I am thinking of a clear and concise way to prove it. (I have background in functional analysis.)

Comment: The map is polynomial in the entries of $A$. Also, a function which is continuous in each coordinate (if the space has the product topology, which it does) is continuous.