# Is $X$ a compact subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: general-topology

In the real vector space ${M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, we define the topology such that the natural bijection from ${M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a homeomorphism. Is its linear subspace $$X:=\lbrace A\in M_2(\mathbb{R}):A^T
A = I_2\rbrace$$ compact?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/compactness-of-the-set-of-n-times-n-orthogonal-matrices or this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422768/prove-that-the-set-of-orthogonal-matrices-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: yes it does, should I delete this answer?

Comment: @PabloGarciaPastor It's better to let the system close it as duplicate than to delete. Thanks for asking!