# Clarification as to why $O(n)$ is closed?

Tags: matrices, differential-topology

In a problem in Guillemin and Pollack they ask to show that $O(n)$ compact. The boundedness comes from the fact that the sum of each row is $1$ and as the matrix is $n \times n$ then the set is bounded. [Multiple](http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/guillemin_pollack.html) [solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447102/orthogonal-matrices-forms-a-compact-set) [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/compactness-of-orthogonal-matrices) go to say that "orthogonal matrices are the inverse image of the element $I$ under the continuous map $MM^{T}$." (3rd link)

Admittedly, I don't know why this fact implies closedness. Can anyone help clarify why this is the case? Is there some theorem that I am forgetting that is being utilized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $F: M(n,\mathbb{R})\to M(n,\mathbb{R})$ to be $M\mapsto M^TM$. Then $O(n)$ is precisely the preimage of the identity matrix $F^{-1}(\{I\})=O(n)$. Singletons are closed in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ (it's a metric space, which is certainly sufficient). Since the preimage of closed sets under continuous maps are closed, it suffices to check that $F$ is continuous. To see this, note that each entry in the matrix $M^TM= F(M)$ is a *polynomial* in the matrix entries of $M$. Polynomials are obviously continuous (in fact they are smooth), so we are done.

Comment: I believe it is a wrong argument: "Since the preimage of closed sets are closed, it suffices to check that  is continuous". Instead, follow the argument by @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez below: "The preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is itself closed" ... (hence)it suffices to check that  is continuous.

Comment: I would expect someone to understand from context that I was speaking of continuous functions (especially considering proving continuity is the focus of the rest of my answer--which is something Mariano didn't bother with). This post is also 4 years old, so I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish by quibbling over my choice of wording here now. But if it makes you happier, I've made an edit.

Comment: +1, now it is much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is itself closed.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.  This follows easily from the definition of continuity.